# Pharo method with multiple arguments

Tags: pharo

I am creating a Pharo Class method that takes 3 arguments. I am using the following code and it gives me the error "Variable or expression expected.."

```
    MethodName: arg1:argValue1 arg2:argValue2
    ^ self var1: argValue1 var2: self var3: argValue2
```

What would be the correct method declaration syntax? Later on, I intend on calling this method like below :

```
    ClassName var1: argValue1 var2: self var3: argValue2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bit that you have to understand when it comes to naming methods in Smalltalk is that the method can be split into multiple parts, delimited by colons (`:`), and that the arguments are inserted after each of those colons. Semantically, that makes a lot of sense, and allows you to use good naming practices so that your code reads almost like an English sentence (which is why the language was named *Smalltalk*).

So for a method that, in Java or a similar "curly bracket language", might look something like this:

```
registerUser(String emailAddress, String password, boolean isAdmin) {...}
```

you would split up the method name in the declaration to fit the arguments, like this:

```
registerUserWithEmail: anEmailAddress password: aPassword isAdmin: aBoolean
```

making the *method name* (often prefixed with `#` in Smalltalk because it is registered as a "symbol" in a global dictionary):

```
#registerUserWithEmail:password:isAdmin:
```

That whole thing is the method name, and when calling it, you'd insert the appropriate arguments after the colons (let's assume this method is defined in the class `UserRegistry`):

```
UserRegistry
    registerUserWithEmail: 'joe@bloggs.com'
    password: 'topSecret'
    isAdmin: true
```

Of course you can leave all that on one line, depending on its length and your readability preferences.

Getting back to your case, you had this:

```
MethodName: arg1:argValue1 arg2:argValue2
```

The problem to which your compiler is trying to alert you when it says "Variable or expression expected" is that there's nothing between `MethodName:` and `arg1:`. I think you may have assumed that `MethodName:` wasn't part of the *method name* but part of the definition.

Some notes:

- by convention, method names use lowerCamelCase
- `#methodName:arg1:arg2:` wouldn't make a very good method name in Smalltalk, because the name should describe what it does and, when arguments come into play, what arguments are expected; the same goes for `#var1:var2:var3:`
- if you're going to be calling this method by sending a message to `ClassName`, then that method needs to be defined on the class side of `ClassName`, not on the instance side
- think about what you're calling/passing in your example - unless you're doing something complicated with a hierarchy of objects, there may not be much point in sending a message to `self` with one of the arguments being `self` as well; ask yourself whether you can simplify something there (hard to be more concrete without knowing what you're trying to do)

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is correct, but `MethodName` is extra and then your method would look like this:

```
arg1: argValue1 arg2: argValue2

  ^ self var1: argValue1 var2: self var3: argValue2
```

Which is a 2 arg method. You can write 3 arg method in a same way:

```
arg1: argValue1 arg2: argValue2 arg3: argValue3

  ^ self var1: argValue1 var2: self var3: argValue2
```

Then what you are doing is calling another 3 arg class method `#var1:var2:var3:` with arguments: `argValue1`, `self`, `argValue2` (I hope this is your intension because this looks weird).